# Where should the logout button go?

Tags: logout, stackexchange

Right now, SE has the logout button next to the "Current Community":

[image]

However, the login has just changed so that if you logout of one site, you log out of all of them.

Where should the logout button go on the page now?

Comment: People log out of stack exchange?  Madness!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it should be up near your account area, since when I first started this site that's where I instinctually looked for the log out at.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider visually grouping it with the Stack Exchange graphic in the top left: log out of everything Stack Exchange related there, or logout of individual areas from the dropdown:

[image]

Or create a top-level Stack Exchange item within the dropdown.

Comment: So next to the inbox?

Comment: Yes, although on reflection I think including the option to log out from Stack Exchange as a top-level item in the current dropdown would be visually cleaner.